# Why doesn't runConduit send all the data?

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing, applicative, xml-conduit, alternative-functor

here's some xml i'm parsing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<row ows_Document='Weekly Report 10.21.2020'
     ows_Category='Weekly Report'/>
<row ows_Document='Daily Update 10.20.2020'
     ows_Category='Daily Update'/>
<row ows_Document='Weekly Report 10.14.2020'
     ows_Category='Weekly Report'/>
<row ows_Document='Weekly Report 10.07.2020'
     ows_Category='Weekly Report'/>
<row ows_Document='Spanish: Reporte Semanal 07.10.2020' 
     ows_Category='Weekly Report'/>
</data>
```

i've been trying to figure out how to get the conduit parser to reject records unless `ows_Category` is `Weekly Report` and `ows_Document` doesn't contain `Spanish`.  at first, i used a dummy value (in `parseDoc'` below) to filter them out after parsing, but then i realized i should be able to use `Maybe` (in the otherwise identical `parseDoc` below), together with `join` to collapse out my `Maybe` layer with the one used by `tag'` event parser that fails based on name or attribute matches.  it compiles, but behaves bizarrely, apparently not even trying to send certain elements to the parser!  how could this be?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Conduit
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import           Data.Foldable
import           Data.String
import qualified Data.Text                  as T
import           Data.XML.Types
import           Text.XML.Stream.Parse

newtype Doc = Doc
  { name :: String
  } deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  r <- L8.readFile "oha.xml"

  let doc = Doc . T.unpack
      check (x,y) a b = if y == "Weekly Report" && not (T.isInfixOf "Spanish" x) then a else b

      t :: (MonadThrow m, MonadIO m) => ((T.Text, T.Text) -> ConduitT Event o m c)
                                     -> ConduitT Event o m (Maybe c)
      t f = tag' "row" ((,) <$> requireAttr "ows_Document" <*> requireAttr "ows_Category") $ \x -> do
        liftIO $ print x
        f x

      parseDoc, parseDoc' :: (MonadThrow m, MonadIO m) => ConduitT Event o m (Maybe Doc)
      parseDoc  = (join <$>) . t $ \z@(x,_) -> return $       check z (Just $ doc x)  Nothing -- this version doesn't get sent all of the data! why!?!?
      parseDoc' =              t $ \z@(x,_) -> return $ doc $ check z             x $ T.pack bad -- dummy value

      parseDocs :: (MonadThrow m, MonadIO m) => ConduitT Event o m (Maybe Doc)
                                             -> ConduitT Event o m [Doc]
      parseDocs = f tagNoAttr "data" . many'
      f g n = force (n <> " required") . g (fromString n)

      go p = runConduit $ parseLBS def r .| parseDocs p
      bad = "no good"

  traverse_ print =<<                              go parseDoc
  putStrLn ""
  traverse_ print =<< filter ((/= bad) . name) <$> go parseDoc'
```

output -- notice how `parseDoc` isn't even sent one of the records (one that should succeed, from 10.14), while `parseDoc'` behaves as expected:

```
("Weekly Report 10.21.2020","Weekly Report")
("Daily Update 10.20.2020","Daily Update")
("Weekly Report 10.07.2020","Weekly Report")
("Spanish: Reporte Semanal 07.10.2020","Weekly Report")
Doc {name = "Weekly Report 10.21.2020"}
Doc {name = "Weekly Report 10.07.2020"}

("Weekly Report 10.21.2020","Weekly Report")
("Daily Update 10.20.2020","Daily Update")
("Weekly Report 10.14.2020","Weekly Report")
("Weekly Report 10.07.2020","Weekly Report")
("Spanish: Reporte Semanal 07.10.2020","Weekly Report")
Doc {name = "Weekly Report 10.21.2020"}
Doc {name = "Weekly Report 10.14.2020"}
Doc {name = "Weekly Report 10.07.2020"}
```

when i tried further simplifying by removing everything to do with `ows_Category`, suddenly `parseDoc` worked fine, establishing the soundness of the idea?  when i instead removed everything to do with `ows_Document`, the problem remained.

i suspect i'm supposed to be doing this with [`requireAttrRaw`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.9.0.0/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:requireAttrRaw), but i haven't been able to make sense of it and can't find doc/examples.

does this have to do with `Applicative` -- now that i think about it, it shouldn't be able to fail based on examining values, right?

UPDATES

i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754296/1441998) from the author for a previous version of the library, which includes the intriguing `force "fail msg" $ return Nothing` in a similar situation, but that abandons all parsing instead of just failing the current parse.

this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265047/how-to-skip-elements-in-xml-conduit#comment71690323_42265047) suggests i need to throw an exception, and in the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.9.0.0/docs/src/Text.XML.Stream.Parse.html#tag), they use something like `lift $ throwM $ XmlException "failed check" $ Just event`, but like `force ... return Nothing`, this kills all parsing, instead of just the current parser.  also i don't know how to get my hands on the `event`.

here's a merged [pull request](https://github.com/snoyberg/xml/pull/93) claiming to have addressed this issue, but it doesn't discuss how to use it, only that it is "trivial" :)

ANSWER

to be explicit about the answer:

```hs
  parseAttributes :: AttrParser (T.Text, T.Text)
  parseAttributes = do
    d <- requireAttr "ows_Document"
    c <- requireAttr "ows_Category"
    ignoreAttrs
    guard $ not (T.isInfixOf "Spanish" d) && c == "Weekly Report"
    return d

  parseDoc :: (MonadThrow m, MonadIO m) => ConduitT Event o m (Maybe Doc)
  parseDoc = tag' "row" parseAttributes $ return . doc
```

or, since in this case the attribute values can be checked independently:

```hs
  parseAttributes = requireAttrRaw' "ows_Document" (not . T.isInfixOf "Spanish")
                 <* requireAttrRaw' "ows_Category" ("Weekly Report" ==)
                 <* ignoreAttrs
    where requireAttrRaw' n f = requireAttrRaw ("required attr value failed condition: " <> n) $ \(n',as) ->
            asum $ (\(ContentText a) -> guard (n' == fromString n && f a) *> pure a) <$> as
```

but the latter leaves open these questions regarding `requireAttrRaw`:

- shouldn't we need to know the namespace if we're in charge of verifying `Name`?
- why does `requireAttrRaw` send us `[Content]` instead of two `Maybe Content`, one each for `ContentText` and `ContentEntity`?
- what are we supposed to do with `ContentEntity` "For pass-through parsing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** In `tag' "row" parseAttributes parseContent`, the `check` function belongs to `parseAttributes`, not to `parseContent`.

---

#### Why it does not behave as expected

[xml-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) is (notably) designed around the following invariants:

1. when parsers are of type `ConduitT Event o m (Maybe a)`, the `Maybe` layer encodes whether `Event`s have been consumed
2. `tag' parseName parseAttributes parseContent` consumes `Event`s if and only if both `parseName` and `parseAttributes` succeed
3. `tag' parseName parseAttributes parseContent` runs `parseContent` if and only if both `parseName` and `parseAttributes` succeed

In `parseDoc`:

- the `check` function is called in the `parseContent` part; at this stage, `tag'` is already committed to consume `Event`s, as per invariant 2
- a stack of 2 `Maybe` layers are `join`ed together:

  - the output of the `check` function, which encodes whether the current `<row/>` element is relevant
  - the "standard" `Maybe` layer from `tag'` signature, which encodes whether `Event`s have been consumed, as per invariant 1

This essentially breaks invariant 1: when `check` returns `Nothing`, `parseDoc`  returns `Nothing` despite consuming `Event`s of the whole `<row/>` element.
This results in undefined behavior of all combinators of [xml-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit), notably [`many'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:many-39-) (analyzed below.)

---

#### Why it behaves the way it does

The [`many'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:many-39-) combinator relies on invariant 1 to do its job.
It is defined as [`many' consumer = manyIgnore consumer ignoreAnyTreeContent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0.1/docs/src/Text.XML.Stream.Parse.html#many%27), that is:

1. try `consumer`
2. if `consumer` returns `Nothing`, then skip element or content using [`ignoreAnyTreeContent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:ignoreAnyTreeContent), **assuming it hasn't been consumed yet by `consumer`**, and recurse back to step (1)

In your case, `consumer` returns `Nothing` for the `Daily Update 10.20.2020` item, even though the complete `<row/>` element has been consumed. Therefore, [`ignoreAnyTreeContent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.8.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v:ignoreAnyTreeContent) is run as a means to skip that particular `<row/>`, but actually ends up skipping the next one instead (`Weekly Report 10.14.2020`).

---

#### How to achieve the expected behavior

Move the `check` logic to the `parseAttributes` part, so that `Event` consumption becomes coupled to whether `check` passes.

Comment: In this answer, I intentionally do not delve into the "is this a bug or a feature" aspect of the question, so as to keep the answer non-opinionated :) .

Comment: thanks so much! should this be apparent from the doc? why not a design where types prevent an inconsistent state? i see how to make `parseAttributes` monadic instead of applicative, so it can fail depending on value, but it took me forever to see how to *actually* fail -- `Alternative.empty` right!?! an example in the doc would be tremendously useful, is this obvious to everyone but me? i suspect the intended use of `requireAttrRaw` is when failure of each attribute is independent from all the others? some doc explaining how to do this would also be very appreciated.

Comment: i think i got `requireAttrRaw` figured out, i updated the bottom of the question with a concrete solution.  it raised a few other questions, would you mind taking a quick look?  :)

Comment: @user1441998 Documentation can definitely be improved, and right now you're in a good position to judge how, so don't hesitate to contribute a pull-request ;) .

Comment: @user1441998 `AttrParser` is both an instance of `Alternative` and of `MonadThrow`, so you can rely on either `Alternative.empty` or `MonadThrow.throwM` to have an attributes parser fail.

Comment: @user1441998 Regarding "is this obvious to everyone but me?", I would argue that: typeclass instances *are* shown in documentation (granted, not in a very *visible* way), and these (`Alternative` and `MonadThrow`) are pretty standard typeclasses that predate xml-conduit, so xml-conduit may not be the right place to document their behavior. At the moment, the documentation implicitly expects readers to know their [typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia), and not to overlook the instances of each data type. Maybe this implicit contract should be documented :) .

Comment: @user1441998 Regarding `requireAttrRaw`, I've never had to use it, but looking at its signature and implementation, I would say it is intended for cases where attributes' name/content are not statically known in advance, so you essentially provide a `Attribute -> Maybe a` function that is repeatedly called for each attribute until it succeeds.